Can I create a react native app with expo without using typescript?
I'm using Expo, but I prefer not to use TypeScript. I've tried reading the Expo documentation to convert tsx files to js, but I couldn't figure out how to do it. Can someone help me with the steps to make this conversion?

This question is similar to: why react native project is creating in typescript ? i want app.js. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You should create a new react native project without the default template. By using the '-template blank' option. This will create a react native project with 'App.js' as the entry point, and no typescript.
E.g)run this command npx create-expo-app appname --template blank
